# redirected page not displays url value

Tags: javascript, php, html

I m trying to redirect page to `1stlink.php` along with a URL parameter. But after I redirect the user, the variable does not display on the page.

Why cant i get the value of `variable` in my redirected page?

```
<html>...    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#btn').click(function() { // The `$` reference here is a jQuery syntax. So we are loading jquery right before this script tag
        var textval = $('#textcat').val();
        window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + textval;
      });
    </script>
```

1stlink.php

```
<?php
echo $_GET['variable'];
?>
```

Comment: The issue may be due to your page unsuccessfully loading the jquery from another site due to connection issues.  Try downloading the jquery source and having your page load it from your site. Also, to obtain a more clear idea about $_GET['variable'] test to see if it's value is null.  You can use in PHP is_null() or $_GET['variable'] != null.

Comment: Is the redirect happening? Ensure that you're passing a valid value to the URL. `window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(textval);` on your PHP page, try `var_dump($_GET)` instead of an `echo`.

Comment: thanks @miken32 encodURIComponent worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the data you're passing to the URL is invalid. You should always use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before adding anything to the URL:

```
window.location = "1stlink.php?variable=" + encodeURIComponent(textval);
```

(I believe jQuery's [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function will also take care of the encoding for you, but have not used it for a single element before.)